# How to manually mark Cruise Control builds as failed?

Tags: cruisecontrol

My config uses the exec command and looks for a custom "errorstr" attribute. But now I want to look for multiple strings as sign for a failure, but the errrorstr attribute does only support a single string. So I thought about validating the logs myself afterwards. I already tried to change the "lastbuildsuccessful" property to "false" and to add an error-attribute to the "build" element. But that does not seem to affect the dashboard.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this? I haven't found a cache or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

The exec command is quite basic and doesn't support what you want to do. You can either write a wrapper script that checks for multiple errors and call that from the exec command, or you could use a more complex builder with better customization options like an ant builder.